Stylus css How to show joined hashes with merge?
With the following stylus css code
foo = { '--width': 10px, height: 20px }

$my_colors={}

$red_colors={
    '--red-1': red,
    '--red-2': pink
}

$blue_colors={
    '--blue-1': blue,
    '--blue-2': cyan
}

.test{
    {foo}
    {merge($my_colors, $red_colors, $blue_colors )}
    loop_merge()
}

loop_merge()
    $merge_colors = merge($my_colors, $red_colors, $blue_colors )
    for key, value in $merge_colors
        {key}: value

I get the following css
.test {
  --width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
{"--red-1":"(#f00)","--red-2":"(#ffc0cb)","--blue-1":"(#00f)","--blue-2":"(#0ff)"}
}

It should appear ordered as in the variable foo, but it appears inside a hash
I even made a function with a for loop, but it doesn't show me anything.
This is the code you should get
.test {
  --width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  --red-1: #f00;
  --red-2: #ffc0cb;
  --blue-1: #00f;
  --blue-2: #0ff;
}


No need to create any function. Just run a for loop in the .test with merge(foo, $my_colors, $red_colors, $blue_colors) as the object.
foo = { '--width': 10px, height: 20px }

$my_colors={}

$red_colors={
    '--red-1': red,
    '--red-2': pink
}

$blue_colors={
    '--blue-1': blue,
    '--blue-2': cyan
}

.test{
 for key,value in merge(foo, $my_colors, $red_colors, $blue_colors)
 {{key}: value}
}

Output:

Update:
Using a reusable function. Here I have used arguments object. Indentation is very important here. It gives an error if you miss/add even a single space. Also, you can directly pass merge(foo, $my_colors, $red_colors, $blue_colors) to the function, instead of storing it in a variable. =>
foo = { '--width': 10px, height: 20px }

$my_colors={}

$red_colors={
    '--red-1': red,
    '--red-2': pink
}

$blue_colors={
    '--blue-1': blue,
    '--blue-2': cyan
}

foo1 = merge(foo, $my_colors, $red_colors, $blue_colors)

fun1()
  for key,value in arguments
  {{key}: value}

.test{
  fun1(foo1)
}


It works, but I wish it was a feature to reuse the code
Another thing I could notice is that you cannot use a variable in which the merge() method was used, for example
.test
  $merge_colors = merge($my_colors, $red_colors, $blue_colors )
 for key,value in $merge_colors
 {{key}: value}


@ztvmark It is possible. I have added code with a reusable function. See the code under the update section of the answer. Indentation is very important here. It gives an error if you miss/add even a single space.
